# __EVENTTARGET not populating after button click + C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp button that produces this html:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$m$g_a2ba5666_c8e9_4bd7_a44a_f9407dbe2199$ctl00$btnAddWebPart" value="Add Report" id="ctl00_m_g_a2ba5666_c8e9_4bd7_a44a_f9407dbe2199_ctl00_btnAddWebPart" />
```

When the button is submitted and the page_load method is hit, I am trying to do this:

```
String target = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

but, for some reason 'target' is empty. I checked to see if __EVENTTARGET is getting populated and it is an empty string. Any ideas as to why this is happening? It is something really silly.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want do this? ASP.NET abstracts this for a reason. That's what events are for.

Comment: I understand that. It is because I am doing SharePoint development, and for some reason I need to do certain actions in PreRender or Page_Load. If I wait to do what I am trying to do in the click event, I have to refresh the page for my changes to take effect. (I am programmatically adding and removing web parts)

Comment: Do you recommend another approach?

Comment: Okay, since SharePoint is kind ridic sometimes, I just made all the click events ajax calls and then did a page refresh after each action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap this button up in an ajaxtoolkit update panel. that way you can update the various page components (add / remove your web parts) within an async call.

This means that the page is partially rendered instead of it being the result of a full postback.

I agree with Josh on this ... handling the event in this way is ugly and against the intended purpose of this part of asp.net  from microsoft.

partial postbacks dont result in that ugly flicker effect so this should produce the result you want and not effect the rest of the page.